# I don't know how to connect to WiFi

Tags: wifi

Just installed elementary os, I don't know how to connect to WiFi?
I read some forums and sites but I didn't found anything interesting and useful

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Wifi icon at the top right. Select your network and enter the password. Unless you are not seeing the triangle shaped Wifi icon? This may indicate that elementary is not detecting your wifi card.